# How to get string to only print when it will fit in the 2d array

Tags: function

I have a 2D array I am using to make a word search puzzle. I have a random start and direction for each word.   I cant find out how to get my method to print the string when it will stay in bounds instead of printing just what fits.

```
    fun loop(){
//        for (word in wordList) {
//
//            testWord(word)
//        }

        testWord("StayInTheBoX123456")
    }

    fun testWord(football:String) {//defines one variable : Boolean
        var row = ((0..(rows - 1)))
        var col = ((0..(cols - 1)))
        // var word = "hello"
//if (football.length < 0 && )
         var dirLength = football.length

        for (letter in football) {
                        when (dir) {
                            "north" -> {

                                board[row--][col] = letter

                            }
                           
                            }

                        }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't I see this question yesterday, from someone else, with the same weird `football` parameter name in the example code...

To check if it'll fit, you need to work out the row and column of the last letter, and check those values are within the grid bounds. You could do that by working out an offset from the start, depending on which direction the word is going

```
// number of letters after the first one (i.e. steps to the end)
val extraLetters = football.length - 1

val endLetterRow = row + when(dir) {
    "northEast", "east", "southEast" -> extraLetters * -1 // makes it negative
    "northWest", "west", "southWest" -> extraLetters
    else -> 0 // north or south - no movement along the row
}
```

and the same deal for the column, and work out if they're both within the grid bounds. I'd stick it in another function personally, so you can do some `isWithinBounds` call. Also randomly trying different start positions isn't a great idea, better to iterate over all the remaining start positions, and you'll either find one that works or you'll know there isn't one and you can stop